# Declaration syntax error in GTuner IV function after compiling

Tags: c, syntax, declaration

I'm using the GTuner language and the [GTuner IV](https://www.consoletuner.com/software/gtuner-iv/) 1.1 compiler.  My code seems to keep outputting the warning after compiling

> GPC error: PressXInput.gpc(18): Declaration syntax error 'combo'

Using GTuner to compile this (Titan Two)

Any help to fix syntax declaration error, or even improvements on my code.

Tried declaring 'combo' as a `bool/int` etc but still same error.

```
bool toggle;

main {
    if (event_active (BUTTON_2)) { 
        toggle = !toggle;
        combo_stop(PressX);
    }
    if (toggle) {
        combo_run(PressX); 
    }
    combo PressX {
        set_val(BUTTON_16, 100.0); 
        wait(100);
        wait(5000); 
    }
}
```

Expected result should show no declaration syntax error with 'combo' after compiling.

Comment: What language is this supposed to be? It is not C++.

Comment: Unrelated: `main` needs a return type of `int`

Comment: Gtuner IV 1.1 uses C like language will change tags. maybe should of asked on official forum instead of here. also dont need to return type 'int' within GTuner, as its C like syntax.

Comment: What is `combo` ?  Where does code define it?

Comment: doesnt define it anywhere, so not really sure if I need to declare it and how. just started on it tonight. code runs but i just wanna see how it could be improved...

Comment: Since this isn't C (for a large number of different reasons), the C tag should go.  But frankly, if there isn't a [GTuner IV](https://www.consoletuner.com/software/gtuner-iv/) tag on Stack Overflow (and there doesn't seem to be one), it's likely the question should be deleted here and asked elsewhere.

Comment: bye @jonathan ....

Comment: I'd like to help; I'd like you to be able to get help.  But there's not much precedent for it on SO.  Sorry.  There is always a first time for everything...

Answer (score 0):

Combos need to be declared outside of main{}

`

```
bool toggle;

main {
    if (event_active (BUTTON_2)) { 
        toggle = !toggle;
        combo_stop(PressX);
    }
    if (toggle) {
        combo_run(PressX); 
    }
 
}

combo PressX {
        set_val(BUTTON_16, 100.0); 
        wait(100);
        wait(5000); 
}
```

`